# What is the correct class modifier to pass through an object without allowing a user to create one

Tags: c#

So I have a Board User Control

```
 public partial class BoardController : UserControl
    {
        List<HotSpot> _hotSpots;
        List<Area> _areas;
        public BoardController()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeHitSpots();
            InitializePlacementArrays();
        }...
```

And a Game Controller

```
public class GameController
{
    private BoardController _board;
    private List<PlayerController> _players;

    public GameController()
    {
        _board = new BoardController();
        _players = new List<PlayerController>();

    }
    public BoardController Board
    {
        get
        {
            return _board;
        }
    }...
```

Now even though I have a public property Board if I make the BoardController class internal I throw an error on the next line

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        game = new GameController();           
        this.Controls.Add(game.Board); //<-- this line 
    }
```

.

```
 Error:  GameController.Board' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

What is the proper class modifier declaration so that classes in the same assembly can use the BoardController but other assemblies can not create a BoardController object nor modify 
BoardController outside of the assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the proper class modifier declaration so that classes in the same assembly can use the BoardController but other assemblies can not create a BoardController object nor modify BoardController inside Game Controller?

To prevent *instantiation*, mark the *constructor* `internal`:

```
internal BoardController() { ... }
```

However, it's not clear what you mean by trying to "modify `BoardController` inside `GameController`".  If you want to prevent modification of the `Board` *property* reference, you've already done that by not providing a setter.  If you are trying to make the `BoardController` class *itself* immutable outside of the assembly, you'd need to make any properties/methods that modify state to also be restricted to `internal`.

Comment: I've rolled back to the original version; the suggested edit (even though it was approved) is directly wrong. An internal constructor *does* allow instantiation within the same assembly; that's the whole point.

Comment: @Tim, heh, I (mis)approved that edit.  It *should* have said "to prevent instantiating outside the same assembly...".

Comment: Considering your 2K votes in the c# tag, I figured as much :)

Comment: Thank you I edited that last line, I meant to say and not modify outside of the assembly.  The internal constructor does prevent creation, I have not tried internal properties yet but that makes sense.  Thanks for the answer.